# LinkedIN API call returns only half the profile values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Trying to add a register/login with LinkedIN feature to my web app. Here is the ExternalLoginCallback method where I call the api.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                    var firstName = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname").Value;
                    var lastName = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname").Value;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email, Name = firstName });
            }
        }
```

Tried catching what externalIdentity is getting from linkedIN and got this:

[image]

as you can see, there are only 11 fields, when there should be more, according to LinkedIn (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

How can I get a hold of the rest? like picture URL, or a second position? (for some reason it only returns the first one)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I do have access to what I need. Its just that I had to call https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=

Answer (score 1):

You need full profile permission to access all fields. For full profile permission, you must be a LinkedIn Partner.

Partner Program Application Form:https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply